# How can i iterate over a basic blocks in a specific routine in intel pintool?

Tags: intel-pin

I tried to iterate over a basic blocks in a specific routine, but i found some problems:

```
VOID Routine(RTN rtn, VOID *v) 
{
  RTN_Open(rtn)
  for (BBL bbl = RTN_BblHead(rtn); BBL_Valid(bbl); bbl = BBL_Next(bbl))
    {  /* some code */ }
  RTN_Close(rtn);
}
```

error: deprecated-declarations,

How can i fix that error, or do it by another way ?

Comment: Are you sure your failures are from this code? Did you try to run a tool with only this code and still saw this warning?

Comment: Yes, i tried but have no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a deprecated-declarations warning because `RTN_BblHead` is now deprecated. Use `RTN_InsHead` instead.

From `include\pin\gen\image.ph`:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT */
/* RTN_BblHead is now deprecated. See RTN_InsHead.
 */
extern PIN_DEPRECATED_API BBL RTN_BblHead(RTN x);
```

This is also mentioned in the documentation: [RTN_BblHead](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/71313/Pin/html/group__DEPRECATED__PIN__API.html#ga793e2a308c99a05c7b2efbe027e8330)

You can also pass `-Wno-deprecated-declarations` to GCC to suppress this warning.

**Edit**

Remember that PIN is above all a DBI (dynamic binary instrumentation) framework: it is extremely good when it comes to instrument the executed  code flow, and less good when it needs to break down non executed code.

Routine instrumentation lets the Pintool inspect and instrument an entire routine when the image it is contained in is first loaded' but as the documentation points:

> A Pintool can walk the instructions of a routine. There is not enough
>   information available to break the instructions into BBLs.

Pin find the instructions of a RTN through static discovery, so Pin cannot guarantee that it will find all the instructions in the RTN and this is even more difficult for BBLs. My guess is that they tried at some point (hence the availability of RTN_BblHead in the past) to provide static discovery of BBLs but the discovery rate was too low (or too error prone) to be deemed acceptable, so the function became deprecated.

In short, yes you need to discover a RTN instructions by instructions (knowing that pin might miss some instructions as this is done statically). You can only discover the BBLs of a routine  if the routine is executed at some point.

Comment: How can i find basic blocks from RTN_InsHead , do you mean i check every instruction's opcode in that routine, or there are another ways to do that ?

Comment: @MosMoh Added some clarification as to why you can't  really go through  the  BBLs of a RTN. You must go through the INSs.